# Rails Admin: Integration Tests, How to get the named paths for models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, integration-testing, minitest, rails-admin

In my rails app, I'm using rails_admin and I need to integration test it.
I'm using capybara and minitest for integration testing.
After clicking link in dashboard, I need to check the path of the current page with expected path.

I want to use named routes which rails_admin provides.
I tried:

```
assert_equal page.current_url, app.rails_admin.dashboard_url
```

This gives correct url in console but doesn't work in integration test. What am I missing here.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Got it working, Wiki page of rails_admin helped.
https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Rspec-with-capybara-examples

I have admin panel on a different subdomain. rails_admin_url has correct path rails_admin.dashboard url doesn't have subdomain by default so I passed as an option. It works.

```
assert_equal page.current_url, rails_admin.dashboard_url(subdomain: 'admin')
# Also following works
assert_equal page.current_url, rails_admin.index_url(model_name: 'post',subdomain: 'admin')
```

Directly using rails_admin worked. In console I used app.rails_admin and it worked. In integration tests using rails_admin.dashboard_url works.

Comment: ok -- you should still use the capybara provided matcher though - `page.assert_current_path rails_admin.dashboard_url(subdomain: 'admin'), url: true` - it'll save you a lot of headaches when working with JS supporting drivers